# How to run a Python code in Apache Druid as a UDF?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, druid

I am trying to run a Python UDF directly on Druid. Running the Python function directly on the machines has many advantages, not the least of which avoiding huge data transfers from and to the remote database server.

For simplicity sake, let I have a simple Python function that I would like to run directly inside the Druid system. Here's a sample function:

```
# Calculates the Inverse of a Matrix 
def matrix_inverse(A):
    return numpy.linalg.inv(A)
```

I would like to run this function remotely and directly in Druid (and not on the client's side). The data used in the parameters `(A)` would be obtained from the database.

How could that be done?

Answer (score 0):

No. Python UDFs are not available...yet.

There are JavaScript user defined functions:
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/javascript.html

Also consider creating a new feature request at: https://github.com/apache/druid/issues

and/or comment on this one: https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/10180